# AIR - Batch File As CMD.exe Argument

Tags: process, batch-file, air, native, cmd

AIR doesn't permit launching .bat files as a native process directly, so apparently i'm suppose to set CMD.exe as my startupInfo executable and pass my .bat file and it's arguments.

i can't get it to work, so i'm hoping it's a syntax problem.  here is my code:

```
var testStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
testStartupInfo.executable = new File("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

var processArguments:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
processArguments[0] = "/c";
processArguments[1] = "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.bat\"";
processArguments[2] = "-testBatPeram1";
processArguments[3] = "-testBatPeram2";
processArguments[4] = "Peram3";
processArguments[5] = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\SaveText.txt";

testStartupInfo.arguments = processArguments;

var test:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
test.start(testStartupInfo);
```

the batch file and its parameters work fine if i manually write them in the command line prompt, so i don't know why nothing is happening when launched from AIR.

Comment: does it work from a regular non user directory c:\Test perhaps? Also arg5 doesn't have "" delimiters

Comment: adding the quotes to argument 5 didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i think that by now (3 months later) you have realized that this doesn't work because your bat file path contains spaces. 
Have you find any workaround or solution or something?

I have a good approximation that could be enough for you:

Instead of passing parameters to your bat try writing to it through its stdinput.
I mean, instead of passing parameters when calling your bat, treat that info as a variable read in execution.